# Android Square API posClient.createChargeIntent() activity without system UI?

Tags: android, square-connect

My friend and I are building a [donation app for Android](https://github.com/sighmon/OpenDonation) that we'd like to function in [kiosk mode](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu) safe for leaving with the general public to be able to make donations on their own.

We can hide the System UI for the `MainActivity`, but were wondering if it would be possible to hide the System UI for the Square Activity when calling:

`Intent intent = posClient.createChargeIntent(request);
startActivityForResult(intent, CHARGE_REQUEST_CODE);`

Or alternatively be able to do a kind of headless charge request and still get the response via `@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Square support:

> Hi Simon,
>
> I am afraid that this feature is not currently available with Square.
>   It is something that I believe we are looking into supporting in the
>   future but I do not have an eta for this right now.
>
> Please keep an eye on your developer site for news for new APIs that
>   we make available.
>
> Thanks,
>
> -- Square | Customer Success squareup.com/au